# Can't get the Nightsong to appear in act 3

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I met (and saved) Nightsong in Act 2, but apparently, I forgot to talk to her AFTER the fight with the end boss. Now, the next step of her quest says that I should get an audience with the wizard that wanted to capture her - that is quickly done, once you can get to the Lower City. But all I can get from that conversation is just a confirmation that Lorroakan wants to imprison her, which, according to Wiki, I should report back to Nightsong.

Can I get her somehow to spawn and continue that quest? I want to get the legendary version of the Moonglaive... Has someone (in a similar position) tried to just kill the wizard?

EDIT: I just killed Lorroakan, the quest is completed, still no sign of Nightsong

Comment: This part is overall confusing. I ended up killing her and taking the "evil" path, but doing so will block you from recruiting two of the extra companions in act 3. Turns out that killing Nightsong set off a long chain of consequences I had no idea of...

Comment: Normally she appears in your camp together with the light cleric, it is there that she actually gives you the glaive saying she picked it back up after it was thrown away. You don't actually need to kill the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common problem<sup>[1](https://forums.larian.com/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=881353), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15ll0yz/comment/jw8hint/), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15o09jj/missing_nightsong_from_camp/), [4](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1086940/discussions/0/6045572169633234650/)</sup>. Hopefully Larian will implement a fix for it soon.

For completeness' sake, another possible cause is having summons with you while travelling through the portal after the final fight with Ketheric Thorm:

> After you fight Thorm the 2nd time, and are about to go into the portal to leave - if you have a summon, Jaheira with a bear familiar for me, it will trigger the NPCs outside the portal when you go through. That breaks Aylin's conversation trigger. If you saved at the portal, you can dismiss before and it fixes it. This just saved my Shadowheart romance. She won't "change" if you don't get Aylin to camp.
> <sup>[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15ll0yz/comment/jw8hint/)</sup>

That being said, apparently there is a fix for those not wanting to go back to an earlier save game to both speak with Nightsong and dismiss all summons before leaving the Mind Flayer Colony.

These steps were posted on Reddit, [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/16eebn9/the_i_forgot_to_talk_to_the_nightsong_act_3_fix_pc/) (credits to user [*sgarn*](https://www.reddit.com/u/sgarn/)):

> - Be somewhere other than Rivington Camp and save your game
> - Find your Baldur's Gate 3 directory and the `/bin` folder within
> - Download the latest version of [Norbyte's Script extender WITH CONSOLE](https://github.com/Norbyte/bg3se/releases)
> - We are using the console to input our commands - You have the right zip file if it has a .dll and a .json file
> - Place both of these files (`.json` AND `.dll`) into your BG3 directory
> - Start up and run BG3. You will get an error at the launcher, ignore it - we'll fix this at the end
> - Load your Save game
> - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of BG3, and you'll find a console window has launched
> - Copy and paste u/sgarn 's script contents into this window: https://pastebin.com/raw/253E5L6G
> - Return to your BG3 game with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or by clicking the window
> - Travel to Rivington, go to Camp (you will not find them in Elfsong Tavern)
> - Speak with Dame Aylin, and progress your quest
> - Exit your camp, just to ensure we're not still mid-script here
> - Save your game
> - Exit BG3
> - Return to the BG3 folder and remove the two files you placed from the zip file here, the `.json` and `.ddl` files
>   This will stop the launcher from displaying error warnings
>
> Endstate: You DID talk to the Nighstong! Enjoy not going back dozens of hours =)